# How to create a hyperlink in Eclipse plugin preferences page?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, preferences

I have an Eclipse plugin with a description and three text fields.

However, I would like to add a group of three radio buttons that perform specific actions on changing the selected choice. I would also like to have a hyperlink to an information page where people can click it and be directed to their browser for viewing the information.

The library `org.eclipse.jface.preference` does not seem to contain such classes and functions.

Would it be possible to guide me to the appropriate resources or give me any hints on how to do that using the Eclipse libraries? I would like to have labels, links, buttons, all in the preferences page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link` to add a hyperlink to a preference page (or any other dialog or wizard):

```java
final Link link = new Link(parent, SWT.NONE);
link.setText("text");
link.setLayoutData(your layour data);

link.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
  {
    // TODO deal with hyperlink selection
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Greg, for this help! I used the org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link library, and it is just great.

Just a question:

Can I build a preferences page ONLY with the widgets from that library and retrieve the user-entered values and use them across the plugin files? For example, can I just remove all preference *FieldEditors and replace them with SWT widgets and still use the user preferences across the plugin?

Regards,

Jeremie

Comment: Yes you can uses ordinary SWT widgets. The field editor classes just wrap the normal widgets and automate the loading and saving in the preferences. You will have to load and save values in the `IPreferenceStore` yourself if you do this. Use `PreferencePage` rather than `FieldEditorPreferencePage` as the base class.