# Eclipse plugin dev - How to add hyperlink on FieldEditorPreferencePage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I was searching for way to add link in Eclipse Preferences page. I quickly found [How to create a hyperlink in Eclipse plugin preferences page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107112/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-in-eclipse-plugin-preferences-page) . The solution however does not fit

```
public class GradlePreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

    ...

    final Link link = new Link(getFieldEditorParent(), SWT.NONE);
    link.setText("link");
    link.setLayoutData(getFieldEditorParent().getLayout());

    link.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent event)
      {
            int style = IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.AS_EDITOR | IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.LOCATION_BAR | IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.NAVIGATION_BAR | IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.STATUS;
            IWebBrowser browser;
            try {
                browser = WorkbenchBrowserSupport.getInstance().createBrowser(style, "NodeclipsePluginsListID", "NodeclipsePluginsList", "Nodeclipse Plugins List");
                browser.openURL(new URL("http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates"));
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
    });
```

However I cannot `addField(link);` as

> The method addField(FieldEditor) in the type FieldEditorPreferencePage is not applicable for the arguments (Link)

Is there as way to add link in `FieldEditorPreferencePage` ? e.g. to compose `FieldEditor` from several part (label, link, Text) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `addField` to just add a normal control to the field editor preference page. The code you have is sufficient. `addField` is only needed for `FieldEditor` derived classes.

Update: Your `setLayoutData` is incorrect, use something like:

```
link.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, false, false, 3, 1));
```

You may have to adjust the number of columns depending on the rest of your page.

Comment: I tried this and got visible result. I tried in `createFieldEditors()` method. In constructor it seems too early.
Should it be `init()`?

Comment: In my page it is in `createFieldEditors()`. I am using `GRID` for the layout, for `FLAT` the layout might need to be different.

Comment: Just bumped into the same problem. For `FLAT` layout, you'll need to call `getFieldEditorParent().getParent()`, as a new composite is created for each field editor. You can find a working example here: https://github.com/PyvesB/eclipse-solargraph/blob/5d5d455ca9861d72e8efacae1928574fcc32fb6e/eclipse-solargraph-plugin/src/main/java/io/github/pyvesb/eclipse_solargraph/preferences/PreferencePage.java#L58